# Communicating that only one object can be "default"

Tags: forms, labels, user-communication

A project we're working on has `place` objects with attributes like name, address, phone number, and URL. Users can view a place and click to call, map, or browse their site.

In our project, *one and only one* place can be set as the "default" place, meaning that its fields are used as the fallback for all empty fields of non-default places. So if a user clicks to call the Sales department, but they don't have a number listed, it will call the default place (Reception, for example) instead.

A content manager creates the places using a set of web forms, but the problem we're running into is how to label the "default place" field in a way which clearly communicates that this will take the "defaultness" from the old default place.

**How do we communicate that there can only be one default place?**

Related, we're debating whether it should be a checkbox that can be checked while editing a place ("default" as an attribute) or a button the manager clicks while viewing a place ("make default" as an action).

**Do you choose a default place by checkbox or button?**

Comment: How about option 3, a "default" dropdown that takes its values from the list of currently known places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a button. Buttons are used for actions to be carries out by the system. In this case, make the item default and un-default the previous default. But be sure to completely communicate how it'll work by adding microcopy.

**[make default]**
(only one item can be default)

Or when the current item is the default:

**[the current item is the default]**

Answer (score 0):

When the user makes one place the default, it may also removed default status from a previous place. Checkbox does not make it clear. In this context use a button.

Ulrich's suggestion also works.

Answer (score 0):

The opening paragraph makes this project sound like a city map and you can click on a location on the map and pull up the mentioned details while the example is a department location within a company. The default "place" makes sense for the example but a default for the city map makes no sense.

In situations such as the example I have used the a hierarchy where the "Company" level is the default, then a department would have any variations to the default and in the system I wrote you could have people in the department and they could have their own level, (say private mobile numbers), and inherit from the department and then the company.